# Angular directive html not loaded (no errors in console)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So i have the following folder structure:

[image]

I have aded the following to my index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/App/lib/App.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/Cafe/lib/Cafe.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/Cafe/directives/cafe-list/cafe-list.js"></script>
```

And my directive looks like this:

```
angular.module('Cafe').directive("CafeList", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: 'js/modules/Cafe/directives/cafe-list/cafe-list.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

        }
    };
});
```

my directive html (located in `js/modules/Cafe/directives/cafe-list/cafe-list.html`

Looks like this:

```
<div class="one-half-responsive">
<div class="service-column material-box">
    <img src="images/pictures/3s.jpg">

    <h3>Mobile and Tablet</h3>
    <em>responsive and ready</em>

    <p>
        All your mobile devices are compatible with material, and it will look gorgeous on your whatever
        handheld you use!
    </p>

    <div class="more">
        <a class="more-link" href="#">READ MORE</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

my view is rather simple and looks like this:

```
<div>
    <cafe-list></cafe-list>
</div>
```

When i run this i get no errors in the console and all i get in the html is the tag `<cafe-list> </cafe-list>` no inner html

Can anyone see what ive done wrong?

my App module:

```
    /**
 * Created by root on 6/3/16.
 */
angular.module('App',[
    'ngRoute',
    'Cafe'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'js/modules/Cafe/views/cafeList.html'
        }).
        when('/phones/:phoneId', {
            template: '<phone-detail></phone-detail>'
        }).
        otherwise('/phones');
    }
]);
```

and on my html: `<html ng-app="App">`

**Cafe module located in ('js/modules/Cafe/lib/Cafe.js')**

```
angular.module('Cafe', []);
```

I can even see that the directive file is loaded!

Comment: try to put a console.log inside the controller/link directive to see if it is loaded

Comment: @AlainIb it doesnt run the console.log() but how can that be? when i can see in my source

Comment: Where is the `Cafe` module initially declared? I see that you have `angular.module('Cafe')`, but that references an existing `Cafe` module.  Did you perhaps mean to have `angular.module('Cafe', [])` instead?

Comment: The module is declared in the file lib/Cafe.js

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with the code where `Cafe` is declared initially?

Comment: @lex ive added it to my code

Comment: Ah...yeah. As others have pointed out it is likely the casing on your directive declaration.

Comment: @Lex when i change the name to caf it works fine? how come i cant using upper case ?

Comment: It's how Angular does its magic. It converts camel case to dash delimited so that it works in all browsers.

Comment: @Lex Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you might be missing an extra closing div tag in your directive.
You can also try `.directive("cafeList",` instead of `.directive("CafeList",` but I doubt that will make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

One issue with you directive is your directive name as in angular if you want to name two word directive then it should be in 'snake case' which will translate into 'camel case'.

```
// directive
angular.module('Cafe').directive('cafeList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'js/modules/Cafe/views/cafeList.html'
  }
});

// call directive
<cafe-list></cafe-list>
```